# detecting arbitrary iBeacon proximity with out app supporting it

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

Can I detect the iBeacon with out the user install any app ? on iOS or on Android .

For example:

A aribetry user enter the store , he dont have the store app.

Can I detect that the user entered the store ? can I do it on iOS or Android ?

I am following the below article

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use iBeacons to detect that a user has entered a store on either iOS or Android, unless an app is installed first.   I am the author of the article you reference.

The reason iBeacons cannot do this without an app is because they are transmit only devices.  You need an app to hear the iBeacon and then use the phone's internet or bluetooth connection to tell computers associated with your store about the user's presence.

What you want is possible with WiFi sniffing sensors that passively detect user phones.  These are good for detecting statistics about customer presence.  See the [MessageRadius](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/message-radius.html) description for an overview of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS this is not possible.

A user may have received & installed a Pass for Passbook that will trigger a lock-screen alert when it is within proximity to a specific iBeacon - but no information will be sent to any web-service about this triggering event. You cannot track a user's location via Passbook.

If the user installs your App then this can send information to your web-service when it detects an iBeacon - but you need to get the user to install the App first ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused about how iBeacon works - A device (beacon) needs to actively transmit an id which can be detected by another device that is listening for the specific UUID.

While an iOS device (or an Android device) can act as an iBeacon it requires an app running on the device to do so and this would not be the typical use case in a retail environment.

Rather, a store's app on the device would register interest in a particular UUID (the UUID assigned to that store's iBeacons).  Entering range of an iBeacon (when you enter a store) would notify the app, which could then take the required action.

The Radius Networks article you linked to essentially describes a "sniffer" app that can scan for all iBeacon UUIDs rather than a specific one.  Neither the iOS CoreLocation or CoreBluetooth libraries do not allow you to do this.

You could write an app on iOS that listens for 'well-known' UUIDs (such as Estimote, Radius Networks etc) - there are several example apps available on the App Store that do this, but the information transmitted is simply a UUID and two numbers, so it would be of limited information to a generic app as you need knowledge of how the store is assigning this information.